# How to kill this C program running inside tmux?

Tags: tmux, c, kill

I'm testing a C program which has a section like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

#define LOOP_MAX 100

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < LOOP_MAX; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
    sleep(1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When it runs, I cannot stop it before `i` counts to `100`. What's the reason?

I have tried: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, all ignored and the program keep running.

Answer (score 0):

myself. Here are the steps you used to solve it:

1. You didn't decompose the problem into smaller ones first and try debugging each of them. And you didn't provide all the information needed for people to help you IMOO. So here is the missing info. (as you yourself provided in the comment section):

   > [...] The problem has many details but in short is related to a terminal program called `fswatch`(, which is an alternative to *inotify* for **macOS**.) [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1708695/how-to-kill-this-c-program-running-inside-tmux?noredirect=1#comment2633494_1708695)

   You were using a *terminal*-program called `fswatch` in a **zsh**-function. Then this problem can be divided into two parts, apparently: (1)`fswatch` and (2)zsh-function.
2. So let's try **without**-(2) first. What if you just run the command:

   ```bsh
   fswatch -o0 "$src_path" | while read -d ""; do \
        make
        for outfile in $( find ./${out_path}/*.${out_expr} ); do \
            $outfile;
        done
    done
   ```

   and as you have found yourself: this command does **not** have the problem as OP -- It's interruptable by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. With this fact we can confirm that the culprit is on step (2), i.e. Calling a terminal program via a zsh-function:

   > The `fswatch`-call is a child process, which doesn't receive the interrupt.
3. With some luck, you thought the problem is at step (1). So you read many issues from the GitHub repo. of [`fswatch`](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch), and you found someone who also called the program inside a function, but with slightly different syntax:

   ```bsh
   while fswatch -10 $src_path; do \
       /* ... details skipped */
   ```

   and it works. Now you get the intended behaviour you want: watch-mode of C++ compiling. Congrets.

Describing problems properly is a hard problem for anyone. Sorry for any inconvenience I made here.